# Why undefined variable?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a simple problem with variable in index.blade.php `{{$last_message}}`
But it not working, it look like "`Undefined variable: last_message (View: G:\OSPanel\domains\flobex\resources\views\chat\index.blade.php)"`

Here is my controller:

```
$user = Auth::user();
    $friend = Auth::user();
    $users = User::all();

//  $last_message = Chat::where('user_id', $user->id)->where('friend_id', $friend->id)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first()->chat;
    $last_message = Chat::select(['chat'])->where('user_id', $user->id)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
  //dump($last_message);

    $search_string = Input::get('search-tag');

    $search_result = null;
    if(!empty($search_string)){
        $search_result = User::where('name', 'like', '%' . $search_string . '%')
            ->orWhere('name', 'like', '%' . strtolower($search_string) . '%')
            ->orWhere('name', 'like', '%' . strtoupper($search_string) . '%')
            ->orWhere('id', strtoupper($search_string))->get();
    }

    $friends = Auth::user()->friends();

    return view('chat.index')
        ->with('user', $user)
        ->with('friend', $friend)
        ->with('friends', $friends)
        ->with('search_result', $search_result)
        ->with('lastMessage', $last_message)
              ->with('users', $users);
```

Here is part of template:

```
@forelse ($friends as $friend)
                  <a href="{{ route('chat.show', $friend->id) }}" class="panel-block" style="justify-content: space-between;">
                    <onlineuser v-bind:friend="{{ $friend }}" v-bind:onlineusers="onlineUsers"></onlineuser>
                      <div class="message-box">

                        {{ $friend->name }}

                      </div>
                  </a>
              @empty

                  <div class="panel-block">
                      You don't have any friends
                  </div>
              @endforelse
          {{$last_message}}
```

Why variable $last_message not working??

Comment: In your controller you pass `lastMessage` but in your view you use `$last_message`

Comment: thank you, i saw it later, stuped error from my side))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing the variable in as `lastMessage` when you're doing `->with('lastMessage', $last_message)`. The variable is actually `{{ $lastMessage }}`, though you probably want to change your `with()` statement to keep consistency.

Answer (score 0):

use  `{{$lastMessage}}` instead of `$last_message`.

```
->with('lastMessage', $last_message)
         ^Key Name       ^data (array/string ...etc)
```

You have to use **Key Name** to catch the data.

Read **[Passing Data To Views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views#passing-data-to-views)**